# selecting :last-child using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a carousel and each anchor in the menu area is linked to selected slide and when the anchor in the menu is selected it receives a `.active` class. 
Ex: link 1 = slide 1. 
I tried to add a stop button instead of next when the carousel reaches the last slider.

```
<nav class="meniu">
    <a href="#">Slide 1</a>
    <a href="#">Slide 2</a>
    <a href="#">Slide 3</a>
</nav>
<div id="slider">
    <ul>
        <li>Slide 1</li>
        <li>Slide 2</li>
        <li>Slide 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is the script that i tried to add

```
if ($('.meniu a:last-child').hasClass('active')){
    //change button arrow to stop sign
}
```

Here is the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/G7P46/1/

Comment: You have a missing plugin reference in the fiddle you have created, add the external plugins in the external plugin`s section

Comment: Where did you try to add that if statement?

Comment: Your fiddle is incomplete...

Comment: try this if ($('.meniu a:last-child').hasClass('active')){ //changes here with button }

Comment: @KrishanaSingh that is what i tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so here's your problem.

When just using the back and forth buttons, you get the element with the 'active' class, and remove the class then add it to the next sibling.  Here's the problem.  If you only use the buttons, no anchor ever actually gets set to active.  So the jquery selector looking for active returns 0. There's no "next" so it can't check to see if the last element has active.

Now, if you click on a link, THEN use the buttons, it works because at least one anchor has been set to "active".

Here is a working fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/G7P46/2/

I updated the gonext function

```
function goNext() {
    if (decount != counter) {
        $('#slider ul').animate({
            left: '-=' + $('#slider').width()
        }, 800, 'swing', function () {

        });
        if ($('.active').length == 0) {
            $('.meniu a:first-child').addClass('active');
        }
        $('.active').removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
        if ($('.meniu a:last-child').hasClass('active')) {
            console.log('change button');
        }

        decount++;
        window.location.hash = decount;

    }
}
```

Notice that I add a check to see if there is any anchor set to active.  If not, I set the first child to active.  I also added the change button if statement. It now gets hit.

Also, I updated the click event

```
$('.meniu a').on('click', function () {
    var goTo = this.id * -$('#slider').width() + $('#slider').width();
    $('#slider ul').animate({
        left: goTo
    }, 800, 'swing', function () {});
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    decount = this.id;
    window.location.hash = this.id;
    if ($('.meniu a:last-child').hasClass('active')) {
        console.log('change button');
    }


});
```

Now it checks the last anchor there to.

Edit:  I updated the fiddle again to have the actual button changing functionanlity

http://jsfiddle.net/G7P46/3/

Comment: the first child in the the list is active when the document loads.

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.meniu a:first-child').addClass('activenum');
    }

Comment: Not in the fiddle you provided.  You have to actually add "class = active" to the first anchor element.

Comment: Here is a 3rd fiddle, with the first anchor having "active"  http://jsfiddle.net/G7P46/4/

Comment: yeah, sorry it's  *active not activenum, typo :P

Comment: In the fiddle you are adding "activate".  Just look at the fiddle. It's working.

Comment: Ty man, you are a life saver. 
I should of added the if/else in a function, that was my problem :)

Answer (score -2):

try this :

```
if ($('.meniu a:last').hasClass('active')){
    //change button arrow to stop sign
}
```

I hope it will help.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/ last-child is what he wants.  There is a problem somewhere else.